# How I extract especific part of class of RangedSummarizedExperiment in R

Tags: r

I have generated a class of data like below

```
> data$primary_diagnosis
  [1] "Adenocarcinoma, NOS"                       
  [2] "Adenocarcinoma, NOS"                       
  [3] "Adenocarcinoma, NOS"                       
  [4] "Adenocarcinoma, NOS"                       
  [5] "Squamous cell carcinoma, NOS"              
  [6] "Adenocarcinoma, NOS"                       
  [7] "Adenocarcinoma, NOS"                       
  [8] "Squamous cell carcinoma, NOS"              
  [9] "Squamous cell carcinoma, keratinizing, NOS"

 class(data)
[1] "RangedSummarizedExperiment"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SummarizedExperiment"
>
```

How I can ***remove*** everything mentioning ***Squamous cell carcinoma*** from this class please?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to change the cell to `NA` or remove the row?

Comment: I want to remove everything related to Squamous cell carcinoma

Comment: Is this an S3, S4 or an R6 class?

Comment: @GradaGukovic S4. The output from `class(data)`, contained in the question, shows this.

Comment: I see, why is "package" not ".GlobalEnv"?

Comment: @GradaGukovic That’s how S4 lookup works: The *class* (rather than the specific object) is defined in the `SummarizedExperiment` package namespace. It gets complicated.

Comment: Thank you. I see now. I just tought "I have generated a class of data like below" ment @fi1d18 wrote the class himself and it made no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `RangedSummarizedExperiment` inverts the expected row/column order for subsetting. I’m not quite clear on the logic but, to answer your question, [the documentation contains an example](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SummarizedExperiment/versions/1.2.3/topics/RangedSummarizedExperiment-class#l_examples) of how to subset a RSE based on a column data:

```
rse[, rse$Treatment == "ChIP"]
```

In your case you need to test for contained text rather than equality, and you need to invert the result:

```
result = data[, ! grepl('Squamous cell carcinoma', data$primary_diagnosis)]
```